# Error por que el input string no está en un formato aceptado

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy creando un programa que trabaja en capas 'POO' en el que necesito editar los datos de un cliente.
Primero, en la capa de Datos o de Acceso de datos tengo un comando para que este introduzca los datos en la base de datos:

```
public DataTable Mostrar()
            {
                using (var connection = GetConnection())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    
                        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            command.Connection = connection;
                            command.CommandText = "select * from Clientes";
                            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                table = new DataTable();
                                table.Load(reader);
                                return table;
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                 return null;
                            }
                        }
                    
                }
                
            }
    
public void Insertar(string nombre, int dni, int telefono, string direccion, string email)
{
    using (var connection = GetConnection())
    {
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "insert into Clientes values (" + nombre + ",  " + dni + ", " + direccion + ", " + telefono + " , " + email + ")";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    }
}
}
```

Después en la capa de dominio he asociado el string que usamos en la capa de datos con el que vamos a usar en la de Presentation:

```
public class ClientesModel
        {
            ClientesDao clientesDao = new ClientesDao();
            public DataTable Mostrar()
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table = clientesDao.Mostrar();
                return table;
            }
    
            public void InsertarClientes(string nombre, int dni, int telefono, string direccion, string email)
            {
                clientesDao.Insertar(nombre, dni, telefono, direccion, email);
    
            }
    
    
        }
```

Aquí es donde creo que sucede el problema, en la base de datos tengo así las columnas:

[image: Imagen de la base de datos]

Entonces creo que no he puesto bien el string y el int anterior.
El problema surge al ir ha editar el dato:

```
private void guna2Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     try
     {
         ClientesModel.InsertarClientes(txtNombre.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtDNI.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtTelefono.Text), txtDireccion.Text, txtEmail.Text);
         MostrarClientes();
         lblClientes.Text = "El cliente se guardó correctamente";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     }
 }
```

Alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Y el error que te sale, ¿cúal es? ¿Qué intentas insertar? ¿Hay algún breakpoint para revisar la sentencia SQL que estás a punto de ejecutar? y de ser este el caso, ¿has copiado dicha sentencia y pegado directamente el sql server?

Comment: @fredyfx Como he puesto en el título, sé que es un error por que he creado un 'Catch (Exception ex)' y este me devuelve un mensaje de error, 'Input string was not in a correct format' y si, he copiado la sentencia y la he pegado directamente, y esta sí funciona. Gracias de corazón por ayudarme

Comment: Buena voz, en todo caso, me late que el problema está en alguna conversión al momento de pasar de capas. Saludos.

Comment: No dejas claro cual es tu problema, por favor se mas puntual en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece que es porque no estás agregando comillas para delimitar las cadenas de texto. Pero un problema aun mayor es el hecho de que tu código está totalmente abierto a inyección de SQL y no quisieras encontrarte con [Bobby Tables](https://es.xkcd.com/strips/exploits-de-una-madre/).

Para evitar ese problema, lo mejor es parametrizar tus consultas y nunca concatenar cadenas con valores que hayan sido ingresados por el usuario en algún momento.

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "insert into Clientes values (@nombre, @dni, @direccion, @telefono, @email);";
    command.Parameters.Add( "@nombre", SqlDbType.nvarchar, 100).Value = nombre;
    command.Parameters.Add( "@dni", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dni;
    command.Parameters.Add( "@direccion", SqlDbType.nvarchar, 4000).Value = direccion;
    command.Parameters.Add( "@telefono", SqlDbType.Int).Value = telefono;
    command.Parameters.Add( "@email", SqlDbType.nvarchar, 100).Value = email;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Gracias! he usado tu código, pero sigue dando error, creo que esta vez el problema biene directamente de la capa Presentation,  en esta parte: 
 ClientesModel.InsertarClientes(txtNombre.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtDNI.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtTelefono.Text), txtDireccion.Text, txtEmail.Text);

Debería sustituirla, o Eliminar la parte de CovertToINt32? 

De todos modos, Muchas gracias por ayudarme